# Multiple info windows in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a little phonegap + google maps project. I have a set of markers, `locations`, that are placed on the map. Now I want to create info windows that will pop up when the marker is clicked. With the code below, it successfully creates an info window for the last generated maker, but not the previous. I have a feeling I am overwriting the same variable over & over again, but I'm not super fluent yet. Do I need to create an array of one of the variables and include it in the loop?

Thanks!

```
for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++ ) {
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat_long.lat, locations[i].lat_long.lon);
            bounds.extend (myLatLng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatLng,
              map: map,
              title: locations[i].name,
              zIndex: i
            });
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                    '</div>'+
                        '<h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+locations.name+'</h2>'+
                        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                        '</div>'+
                '</div>';

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
            console.log(marker);
        });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [google maps api multiple markers info window only showing last element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674194/google-maps-api-multiple-markers-info-window-only-showing-last-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out. Made a function to handle it

```
    for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++ ) {
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat_long.lat, locations[i].lat_long.lon);
        bounds.extend (myLatLng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: locations[i].name,
          zIndex: i
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        buildInfoWindow(marker,map,locations[i]);
    }
```

function

```
function buildInfoWindow(marker,map,locations){
    var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                        '</div>'+
                            '<h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+locations.name+'</h2>'+
                            '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                            '</div>'+
                    '</div>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        console.log(marker);
    });
}
```