# Converting string of coordinates to lat long array for google maps api v3 returning longitude as 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've taken a look at all the other questions but basically, I have a long list of coordinates as a string that looks like this: "42.2723998, -81.23239 ... 42.84099, -81.3990398" which I have use javascript .split(" , "); on so that its now an array called coordinate[] of strings each holding one coordinate and then using the below code:

```
// create a coordinate Array
    var polygonCoords = [];
    // creates a new LatLng
    var j = 0;
    var z = j + 1;
while (z < coordinate.length) {
    if ((j%2) === 0) {
    var co1 = parseFloat(coordinate[z]);
    //document.write(coordinate[j]);
    var co2 = parseFloat(coordinate[j]);
    //document.write(co2);
    var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(co1,co2);

    polygonCoords.push(newLatLng);
} else {
    var co2 = parseFloat(coordinate[z]);
    var co1 = parseFloat(coordinate[j]);
    var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(co1,co2);
    polygonCoords.push(newLatLng);
}
    z++;
    j++;
    }
```

but when I print out the polygonCoords array, it always returns the longitude as 0 and I've also parsed it from a string as well using parseFloat(). Also when I explicitly return the longitude by its own, it returns the actual number. I just need it to work so that I can create an array of LatLngs that I can later use as a path for a polygon.

Comment: Why such a convoluted way of going through the coordinates?  Could you please provide a complete example array?  Why are you spliting on " ' "?  Doesn't look like that character is in the example string you provided.

Comment: Oops, sorry, meant to write the comma (",") for split, sorry, wrote this question too fast

Comment: Basically what I'm working on is creating an array of polygons and then attaching a customized infowindow to each one where the information for the infowindow should be stored in a kml file, however, I cannot change the kml file so I'm using javascript to basically do the job

Comment: What do you mean you "cannot change the kml file"?  Why are you re-inventing the wheel?  There are third party KML parsers that will parse KML for you and create native google maps javascript API v3 polygons (geoxml3, geoxml-v3).

Comment: Here is the original string : -81.2338973051004,42.9872488004691,0 -81.2337121944366,42.9872547337441,0 -81.233528492502,42.9872724884156,0 -81.233347597307,42.9873019293669,0 ... (its too long to put in one comment and i keep getting (42.9872488004691, -81.23389730510041),(42.9872488004691, 0),(42.9872547337441, 0),(42.9872547337441, 0),(42.9872724884156, 0),(42.9872724884156, 0),(42.9873019293669, 0),(42.9873019293669, 0),(42.9873428325462, 0),(42.9873428325462, 0)... 
also just the kml file holds many different polygons which is why I also need to separate those out

Comment: Yep, i've tried geoxml3 and other parsers but it doesn't read the data that I have on my kml file, its typed/schema data (https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/extendeddata) which is not parsed or read by geoxml3 so I've actually parsed it myself by just grabbing the data using xml and javascript, also the kml file is generated programmatically using a system so I can't do anything about it, yep, i also know that I am basically reinventing the wheel here but I cant find a solution

Comment: actually you're probably correct, the coordinates are stored in the kml with <coordinates> tags, would i be able to parse that using geoxml3 as an array of latlng? Sorry for the trouble

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569401/google-maps-given-the-lat-long-coordinates

^Actually I've taken a look at the above question, and maybe it would work if I used arrays within an array

Comment: Sure it can be made to work.  You still need to parse the coordinates from your KML into those arrays.  BTW - I would suggest you address the comments by _updating_ your question to include that data, that will make it more complete for future readers, and any code can be formatted to be readable in the question.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, first time using stackoverflow so I'm not too familiar with the process and everything :)

Comment: Actually I think i've found the problem, after using javascript's split(","), the array of strings I get returned gives me "0  -81.3983893" or something similar for each longitude value, which I think is causing the problem

Comment: That would do it. But hard to reproduce with the information provided in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've fixed it, somehow when I grabbed the longitude from the kml file, it would be in the form of 0 -81.290390... and so whenever i parsed it into float, it would recognize it as 0 instead of -81.293848. Now its done properly, and printing out the correct floats.